# Strange Puzzle - Invalid memory access of location

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

The error message I'm getting consistently is:

> Invalid memory access of location 0x8 rip=0x10cf4ab28

What I'm doing is making a basic stock backtesting system, that is iterating huge arrays of stocks/historical data across various algorithms, using java + eclipse on the latest Mac Os X.

I tracked down the code that seems to be causing it. A method that is used to get the massive arrays of data and is called thousands of times. Nothing is retained so I don't think there is a memory leak. However there seems to be a set limit of around 7000 times I can iterate over it before I get the memory error.

The weird thing is that it works perfectly in debug mode. Does anyone know what debug mode does differently in Eclipse?

Giving the jvm more memory doesn't help, and it appears to work fine using -xint. And again it works perfectly in debug mode.

```
public static List<Stock> getStockArray(ExchangeType e){
    List<Stock> stockArray = new ArrayList<Stock>();
    if(e == ExchangeType.ALL){
        stockArray.addAll(getStockArray(ExchangeType.NYSE));
        stockArray.addAll(getStockArray(ExchangeType.NASDAQ));
    }else if(e == ExchangeType.ETF){
        stockArray.addAll(etfStockArray);
    }else if(e == ExchangeType.NYSE){
        stockArray.addAll(nyseStockArray);
    }else if(e == ExchangeType.NASDAQ){
        stockArray.addAll(nasdaqStockArray);
    }
    return stockArray;
}
```

A simple loop like this, iterated over 1000s of times, will cause the memory error. But not in debug mode.

```
for (Stock stock : StockDatabase.getStockArray(ExchangeType.ETF)) {
    System.out.println(stock.symbol);
}
```

Comment: Clearly this is a JVM bug. JIT optimizations may be disabled in debug mode, which would explain the absence of error. The threshold at which the error happens may be related to the compile threshold. You can manipulate this threshold with a JVM param to see if it's correlated.

Comment: what's the type of `etfStockArray`, `nyseStockArray` and so on?

Comment: Is etfStockArray modified during addAll? There does not seem to be a provision for that.

Comment: This is a clear scenario for when you should be setting the `initialCapacity` of your `ArrayList`... the default is almost certainly not going to be big enough and the resizing is really slow... and who knows, it may lead to your memory error

Comment: If you are getting this error is it due to a bug in your JVM or a native library it is using.  BTW: You should never need to create these lists more than once, I would cache them in an EnumMap.

Comment: They are also ArrayList<Stock>. Basically just combining them into a new arraylist and returning it. Nothing is modified or threaded.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone, I really appreciate it. And setting -XX:CompileThreshold=100000 does fix it. @Marco, I'll accept if you want to submit your comment as an answer.

Comment: is StockDatabase using hibernate by any chance? or any other type of ORM?

Comment: @dstarh Nope, nothing fancy just a bunch of very large ArrayLists, strings, and doubles, looped through thousands of times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably too late, but for other people who have this problem, this is how you fix it.
Instead of using the enhanced for loop, use a normal one. I'm serious.

ex:

```
for(int stock = 0; stocks < StockDataBase.getStockArray(ExchangeType.ETF).size(); stock++)
```

You can take it from there.

This is due to the fact that you are creating new objects each time the enhanced for loop loops, but not in the regular for loop. The garbage collector probably doesn't have enough time to address all of those new objects at once.

Answer (score 2):

Rob, your code could be far more efficient and use a lot less memory if you use a lot of the suggestions in the comments... which would naturally fix your original problem.

```
public enum ExchangeType {
    ALL, ETF, NYSE, NASDAQ;

    private static EnumMap<ExchangeType, List<Stock> stocks;

    // Do this during your initialization routine, or if something changes
    public static loadStock(ExchangeType et, List<stock> stockList) {
        stocks.put(et, stockList);
    }

    public List<Stock> getStocks() {
        return stocks.get(this);
    }
}
```

Then, for security, you could even implement your own `ImmutableList`...

```
public class ImmutableList<E> implements List<E> {
    private ArrayList<E> _internal;

    // Do something like this for modification methods
    public boolean add(E e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("This list is immutable!");
    }

    // Do something like this for access methods
    public E get(int index) {
        return _internal.get(index);
    }
}
```

This should get your memory under control AND greatly improve performance!!

In any event, if this doesn't fix your problem, as a lot of others said this is probably a JVM bug. As you noted the compile threshhold (i.e. `-XX:CompileThreshold=100000`) is a quick-and-dirty fix that should solve your problem at least for now...

Comment: Thanks, I did swap everything out for EnumMaps and it does run a bit faster. However the optimizations doesn't affect the memory error, which I'm assuming is just a jvm bug.

Comment: Wait, you're not copying the arrays constantly and it still gives the memory error?

Comment: Yeah, so far only increasing the jvm compile threshold fixes it. If you want to add what others said about it being a jvm bug, I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution, but you say you don't modify the lists, so you could do something like this:

```
public static List<Stock> getStockArray(ExchangeType e){
    if(e == ExchangeType.ALL){
        List<Stock> stockArray = new ArrayList<Stock>(nyseStockArray.size() + nasdaqStockArray.size());
        stockArray.addAll(nyseStockArray);
        stockArray.addAll(nasdaqStockArray);
        return stockArray;
    }else if(e == ExchangeType.ETF){
        return etfStockArray;
    }else if(e == ExchangeType.NYSE){
        return nyseStockArray;
    }else if(e == ExchangeType.NASDAQ){
        return nasdaqStockArray;
    } else {
       return new ArrayList<Stock>();
}
```